# TDD with python, unexpected unittest error

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, python-unittest

This is my code;

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest

class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setup(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(5)

    def teardown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_can_start_list_and_retrieve_later(self):
    # checkout the homepage
        self.browser.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000')

    # check title and header
        self.assertIn('To-Do', self.browser.title)
        self.fail('Finish the test')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(warnings='ignore')
```

which results in the following error:

```
$ python3 functional_tests.py 
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_can_start_list_and_retrieve_later         (__main__.NewVisitorTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "functional_tests.py", line 15, in     test_can_start_list_and_retrieve_later
self.browser.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000')
AttributeError: 'NewVisitorTest' object has no attribute 'browser'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

the code is taken from TDD with python

My code matches with what has beeen written in the tutorial but should produce an assertIn error as the page has yet to be set up. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are typos: `setup` should be [`setUp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp). And `teardown` should be [`tearDown`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown).

```
class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(5)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes the code fail as expected. Could you explain to me why that makes it work? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @w0nk, The names of the methods should match (Python does distinguish identifier cases). And the `TestCase` expect `setUp`, `tearDown`, not `setup`, `teardown`.